# Facebook API Lead Ad webhook lead retrieval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have setup a webhook for Facebook Lead Ads

It is receiving data like this:

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"718196074978224","time":1453818316,"changes":[{"field":"leadgen","value":{"ad_id":"399579767903","adgroup_id":"971076277715","created_time":1453789516,"form_id":"930912320812","leadgen_id":"151977133461","page_id":"718196074978224"}}]}]}
```

The next step is to retrieve the details.

The docs say 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/
but if I use the leadgen_id (151977133461) this returns
"singular published story API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"

I've also read that _ might work, but that returns a different error.

Comment: Could you give answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229099/how-to-set-webhook-for-facebook-lead-creation please..

Comment: How to setup webhook for tracking of leads on facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question: subscribed_apps wasn't set up correctly

Comment: can you tell me what exactly was the error? can't manage to get it working

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259024/facebook-api-cant-retrieve-facebook-lead-ads

Answer (score 0):

You just need page access token to retrive the values from the lead. You need to make a GET call on

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<leadgen_id>?access_token=<page_access_token>
```

For more info go through this link it will help you: http://tanmayverma.com/reactjs/storing-facebook-lead-data-in-our-database-in-real-time-using-reactjs-meteorjs-and-fbs-javascript-sdk/