# Facebook API: Can't retrieve Facebook Lead Ads

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I have set up successfully a webhook to point to my callback URL and it receives the following example data:

```
Array
(
[object] => page
[entry] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 297269987142139
                [time] => 1454876106
                [changes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field] => leadgen
                                [value] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ad_id] => 410908499427
                                        [adgroup_id] => 238113717077
                                        [created_time] => 1454847306
                                        [form_id] => 577581087825
                                        [leadgen_id] => 441393665441
                                        [page_id] => 297269987142139
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
 )
```

But if I try to retrieve the data associated with the `leadgen_id` as [explained by facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5), it doesn't work:

```
 use FacebookAds\Object\Lead;

 $form = new Lead('441393665441');
 $form->read();
```

I get the following error: `Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`

I've tried everything but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I am sending test leads like this:

```
    curl \
    -F "object_id=<PAGE_ID>" \
    -F "object=page" \
    -F "field=leadgen" \
    -F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
    -F 'custom_fields={"page_id": <PAGE_ID>}' \
    "https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<APP_ID>/subscriptions_sample"
```

Comment: if it's documented and not working, feel free to submit a bug

Answer (score 11):

I also struggled to get this working, and it seems that nobody has made any copy-and-paste solution that seemed to work.

This PHP function works for me:

```
function getLead($leadgen_id,$user_access_token) {
    //fetch lead info from FB API
    $graph_url= 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/'.$leadgen_id."?access_token=".$user_access_token;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    //work with the lead data
    $leaddata = json_decode($output);
    $lead = [];
    for($i=0;$i<count($leaddata->field_data);$i++) {
        $lead[$leaddata->field_data[$i]->name]=$leaddata->field_data[$i]->values[0];
    }
    return $lead;
}
```

You can use the function with this sample code:

```
//Take input from Facebook webhook request
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$leadgen_id = $input["entry"][0]["changes"][0]["value"]["leadgen_id"];

//Token - you must generate this in the FB API Explorer - tip: exchange it to a long-lived (valid 60 days) token
$user_access_token = 'TOKENID';

//Get the lead info
$lead = getLead($leadgen_id,$user_access_token);//get lead info
```

From here on you can for example send a realtime mail by getting attributes and values in the lead:

```
//Create an email with the lead info
$mail="<html><body><h2>New lead</h2><blockquote>";
$mail.="Lead id: ".$leadgen_id."<br>";
foreach($lead as $attr=>$val) {
    $mail.=$attr.": ".$val."<br>";
}
$mail.="</blockquote></body></html>";
```

I hope this helps. Notice that the subscriptions_sample lead doesn't contain any fields. You can test with your own Facebook profile to get real data.

Comment: What permissions do I need for the Access Token?

Comment: @john sandy thanks. its working i managed somehow to get the token but i cant seem to remember which steps i did to generate it... also i need to generated the 60 days valid token and cant seem to find a way can someone please help  with this subject?

Comment: How can I create an access token for one account? I'm not making an app for lots of accounts, just a single business account to get leads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @John Sandy It helped a lot:-)

However if someone else is also struggling please use below url in browser itself.

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/leadgen_id?access_token=xxxxxxxx`

*Note*: insert your leadgen_id and access token

Hope this will help

thanks
Pranav

Comment: how to get leadgen_id  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using JavascriptSDK and ReactJS. You just need page access token to retrive the values from the lead. Make sure you already subscibed the page with your app. You need to make a GET call on:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/<leadgen_id>?access_token=<page_access_token>
```

For more info kindly check the link: http://tanmayverma.com/reactjs/storing-facebook-lead-data-in-our-database-in-real-time-using-reactjs-meteorjs-and-fbs-javascript-sdk/