# Testing Facebook Lead Ads Webhooks

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using Lead Ads and want to integrate them with my application. There is quite nice [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/webhooks/v2.5) for that, but I still don't know how to test webhooks. When I fill the form from the `Preview Ad` feature from `Ads Manager`, it doesn't seem to fire the webhook. Same happens with the testing feature, which is a call to `/<APP_ID>/subscriptions_sample` edge. According to docs, it should do the following:

> This will deploy a stubbed payload similar to the one that the realtime updates uses.

But my callback URL is never opened with this, even though the response is:

```
{
  "success": true
}
```

How can I force this webhook to happen?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky, but you can test in two ways:

1. Simply by creating new lead ads in Power Editor and previewing them on mobile or desktop. You fill out the form with your own data. The downside to this is that you can only fill out a form once. Then you'll have to create a new form, switch your ad to use the new form and try again. You'll end up with a bunch of test forms since there is currently no way to delete forms.
2. By making the call to //subscriptions_sample as you suggest yourself. This works somehow, but the lead will be empty. You'll get a leadgen-id which you can get lead data from, but there are no fields in the lead. If this doesn't work, you'll need to check a few things:

a) is your app subscribed to the page

b) is your webhook URL correct

c) are there any errors in your webhook URL

d) are you using a valid token

e) ...

Notice that tokens expire so you should change your token for a long-lived token which will be good for 60 days. I hope this will help you since it's not quite so easy to set up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't expect anyone to answer, because lead ads are still quite fresh. So, to start: can you confirm that the Preview Ad feature doesn' fire a webhook? What I can say is that: 1) Yes, the page is subscribed to the app, 2) Yes, my webhook URL is correct, I also debug it with Postman and everything's fine, 3) No errors, 4) Yes, the token is for sure valid. I put some debugging code to check whether my website is ever opened by Facebook. It is on verification step (GET method), but then is never opened on actual lead insertion (POST method).

Comment: Preview ads DOES fire a webhook. It's the most reliable way to test, but also takes 3-4 minutes to set up a new form and ad for each test. The subscriptions_sample call also fires a webhook. The difference is that in subscriptions_sample there are no fields in the lead, but the lead is still valid.
I tested with subscriptions_sample for the most part since it's fast. Maybe my reply here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259024/facebook-api-cant-retrieve-facebook-lead-ads/35602419#35602419 can help you.

Comment: I will take a look. By the way, did you know that Facebook introduced deleting your own leads? It seems like you no longer need to create new ads to test. Please take a look at the very bottom of the documentation page I mentioned. Can you confirm whether the hook will be fired multiple times if you delete your lead and send it again to the same form?

Comment: Oh cool, thanks for this. They are changing this all the time and the "Deleting Test Leads" is very new. This makes testing a whole lot easier. I think deleting forms must be on its way as well.

Comment: I still don't know why I'm not receiving any POST ping from Facebook. :( Nothing happens neither on `subscriptions_sample` nor lead form submission. I will try on another server, maybe Vagrant Share rejects Facebook's ping.

Comment: BTW can you please tell me one thing, because it's not that clear from the docs. Does it matter what response body you have for those POST pings? From what I understood, it only matters to return `hub_challenge` for GET ping, but for POST it's only important to return `200` status and no matter what response. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but my script returns 200 without the hub_challenge and it works fine on real ads. I only had to return the hub_challenge when setting up the webhook in the app. So I guess what you write is correct.

Comment: I tried on another server. It seems like it works now, I'm having a ping after around ~5 minutes from submitting the form. But I encounter another problem now. In the ping's body, `form_id` for each entry is something weird, it doesn't match any of my leadgen forms ids. What is this `form_id` value actually refering to? If I try to get `/{form_id}/leads`, using the `form_id` from this ping's body, I'm getting the error. If I use actual form ID, it works.

Comment: Okay, now I'm totally confused and I don't know what causes the webhook to work. I randomly get it working or not.

Comment: That's sounds weird. When you use the subscriptions_sample call you'll probably get a random form id, but with real ads you should get the right form id. I noticed that sometimes there can be up to 5-10 minutes delay. Too bad not much help or support can be found online yet.