# How to get formId of leadgen webhook on facebook?

Tags: facebook, webhooks

I have created webhook for tracking of leads on my facebook page.
I need formId of lead but my logs shown as below.

```
[field] => leadgen
      [value] => stdClass Object
            (
              [ad_id] => 0
              [form_id] => 2.6147643765585E+14
              [leadgen_id] => 2.6356365078047E+14
              [created_time] => 1491489109
              [page_id] => 4.3192338381483E+14
              [adgroup_id] => 0
            )
```

[form_id] is shown like 2.6147643765585E+14 but actual formId is different.I think it is in encoded form right?

How to get formId in decoded form, I mean original formId like

```
 "field" => "leadgen",
      "value" => array(
        "leadgen_id" => 123123123123,
        "page_id" => 123123123,
        "form_id" => 12312312312,
        "adgroup_id" => 12312312312,
        "ad_id" => 12312312312,
        "created_time" => 1440120384
      )
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That happens when large numeric strings are parsed as numbers when decoding the JSON - this is too large for an integer, so it becomes a float, and looses precision. If you are using PHP, check the documentation for json_decode - it has a parameter to parse such values into strings.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I fixed it.